# printing a str and int in a single statement

Tags: python, scripting

I've begun my first scripting class. I'm am currently stuck in the string formatting section.

The instructions for this problem are, **"Write a single statement to print: user_word,user_number. Note that there is no space between the comma and user_number."**
They provide part of the code to start,

user_word = str(input())
user_number = int(input())

I've had trouble getting errors combining strings and integers in single statements and I am a bit lost on where to start on this. This is also my first time on stack overflow.

Comment: Take a look at the [output formatting documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html), it should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
print(user_word+","+str(user_number))
```

It should work.
This way, you cast you int to string and then you concatenate.

Comment: Much appreciated.